# Synaptic freezes at start

Tags: freeze, synaptic

this is a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04, using Gnome Flashback Mode. Synaptic made problems from the beginning, directly after its installation.

Ubuntu 12.04, which is installed in parallel, never had problems with Synaptic.

After starting synaptic, the left list is populated while the loading bar is displayed at the bottom. After the loading bar disappears, nothing changes (still not enabled/"clickable") and after a while the synaptic window becomes grey. One CPU is at 100% load then with the synaptic process.

Then I have to kill it and remove the `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` file prior to being able to use apt or the software center.

Those other two tools work without a problem. Interesting: sometimes synaptic works! I can not identify why.

I have no clue on how to debug or solve this.

There is nothing in syslog and no error when called via command line.

As requested, some hardware informations:

- Samsung XE700T Slate PC (tablet style)
- Intel Core i5 2467M
- 4 GB RAM
- 64 GB SSD

Comment: Can you give some details about your hardware? RAM memory etc, what computer, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether you are [hit by this bug](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-accessibility-bugs/2014-January/006481.html).

In my case it helped to inactivate the virtual keyboard "Onboard".

Comment: Thank you ... can not believe it, but this was the problem!

Comment: That is so strange, but it worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: My best answer.